# How to check a record de-activation with RSpec 3.12?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

My Playground controller does not really delete records, it flags them as inactive if one wants to remove a Playground:

```
def destroy
  @playground.set_as_inactive(current_login)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to playgrounds_url, notice: t('.Success') } #'Playground was successfully deleted.'
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Where **set_as_inactive** method simply sets the **is_active** flag to false and traces who did the change.

This feature works as expected in the application, but when I try to test it in Playgrounds requests, the is_active flag seems not be set to false:

```
  describe "DELETE /destroy" do
    let(:playground_tbd) { create(:playground) }
    it "destroys the requested playground" do
      expect {
        delete playground_url(playground_tbd)
      }.to change(Playground.visible, :count).by(-1) 
      expect(response).to have_http_status 302
      expect(response).to redirect_to(playgrounds_url)
    end
    it "renders the expected status" do
      get playground_url(playground_tbd)
      expect(playground_tbd.is_active).to eq(false)
    end
  end
```

My explanations:

1. playground_tbd is created specifically for this test, to be deteled afterwards
2. Playground.visible returns only active playgrounds - the count has changed (1 deleted) which lets me think that the test actually works
3. When I reload and check playground_tbd, it says that is_active is true !?!

What did I miss here?

Comment: the tests run separately -- your second test is running against the record in its original state -- hence iis_active is true. You need to delete it in the test to get the expected behavior.

Comment: I think the syntax should be `{Playground.visible.count}` parens, not brackets

Comment: What @dbugger said! `playground_tbd` in "destroys the requested playground" is different from `playground_tbd` in "renders the expected status". Tests are designed to run in isolation and any order so each setup should (generally) be able to run independently.

Comment: Do you mean that the let instruction is repeated for each test in the describe bloc? Then I added 2 lines: 
      - delete playground_url(playground_tbd)  - and: 
      - playground_tbd.reload - 
and it works! Thanks a lot !

Comment: let statements are run fresh in every test.